# What help systems (KB's) are mostly used in bigger companies?

Tags: usability, help, documentation, software

I know the first answer would normally be NO help system at all.
make your UI as intuitive as possible. second would probably be about studies showing no one reading help files and the better option of implementing direct help into your software.

as I'm interested in the software bigger companies use for their help systems (documentation about workflows and other knowledge base relvant stuff) I'd be glad to nevertheless receive an appropriate answer.

cheers

Comment: That first answer that you mentioned would be coming from people living in a bubble or not having any experience with complex, enterprise-level systems. We use [Nanorep](http://www.nanorep.com/) which is pretty great.

Answer (score 1):

I know that Zendesk is widely used. In the agency I last worked for we made our own knoweldgebase in Drupal which worked really well for us. Zendesk has a pretty sophisticated ticketing system though which is a huge advantage.